# Navigate to an Activity from NavHost or a full screen Fragment

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

Is there a best practice when it comes to navigation to a new activity in compose with a NavHost?

This will take me to a new activity

```
val context = LocalContext.current
...
onClick = {
    val intent = Intent(context, ListActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(key, value)
    context.startActivity(intent)
}
```

However I am not taking advantage of the navigation router.  Checking the android compose docs, I could find anything related to navigation to another activity.  What am I missing?

Comment: that's the correct way. Compose navigation is limited to current compose view - when you run it in one activity, you can't interact with other activities. If you're looking for the most compose way - it is not using multiple activities and only navigating between navigation routes in a single acitivity.

Comment: @PylypDukhov if navigating between routes in a single activity is it possible and appropriate to change the navigation icon to a back arrow and use a full screen composable?

Comment: You're talking about app bar icon? Ofc you can control it depending on navigation state. fullscreen mode can be enabled/disabled as per composable using [Accompanist libraries](https://google.github.io/accompanist/systemuicontroller/) or you can adopt any other code you can find for activity with `DisposableEffect`